# fade with next and prev button jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to script a little image rotator with fade animation,
I have some divs and I add two buttons next and prev :

```
<div id="target" class="cible" style="height: 240px;">   
     <div id="211" class="block" style="display: block;"> </div>
     <div id="491" class="block" style="display: none;"> </div>
     <div id="496" class="block" style="display: none;"> </div>
```

and the div with button

```
   <div id="next" class="next"></div>
   <div id="prev" class="prev"></div>
```

I try with .next() and .prev() and addClass(), functions but I didn't really the mechanism to know the current div. If someone can explain it

Thanks

I try this, it works but not really.

```
 $(".next, .prev").click(function() {
var next_visible = $(this).hasClass(".prev") ? 
        $(".block:visible").prev(".block") : 
        $(".block:visible").next(".block");
$(".block").hide();
next_visible.show();
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing many the custom slider, this is the method I use. I do it this way to minimize the number of jQuery objects created. This is because you never are testing to find the active elements, its managed by variables. Doing anything like $(elem:visable) or $(elem).hasClass is a waste of a jQuery object, you should not be using jQuery to detect the state of your application unless you really really have to.

```
//create a universal block jQuery object, and give it an index property (current)
var blocks = $('div.blocks');
    blocks.current = 0;

var next   = $('.next'),
    prev   = $('.prev');

//make a universal slide handler
function blockControl(index){
    //using hide and show here to fit your example, 
    //but this is where you would do slide or fades or whatever animation
    //the important part is it is 'showing' based on .eq()
    blocks.hide().eq(index).show();
}

//setup the initial state
blockControl(blocks.current);

next.on('click', function(){
    //move current up one        
    blocks.current ++;
    //test if its the last block
    if( blocks.current >= blocks.length ){
        //prevent over reach
        blocks.current = blocks.length;
        //handle how the last slide will work, you could loop back the beginning or 
        //whatever. Here we are just going to hide the next button.
        next.fadeOut();
        prev.fadeIn();
    }else{                        
        //insure prev button is visalbe
        prev.fadeIn();            
        //do slider
        blockControl(blocks.current);
    }           
});

prev.on('click', function(){
    //move current down one        
    blocks.current --;
    //test if its the first block
    if( blocks.current <= 0 ){
        //prevent negative numbers
        blocks.current = 0;
        //Here we are just going to hide the prev button. But we also could put in control 
        //to loop the last or whatever
        prev.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn();
    }else{                        
        //insure next button is visalbe
        next.fadeIn();            
        //do slider
        blockControl(blocks.current);
    }           
});
```

The separation of logic here is important. Having a single handler for controlling the visuality of blocks, means it can be triggered by things other than the arrows. Also arrow logic and controller logic can change independent of each other. Also you can always access which element is currently on display from any part of the application, without testing or querying.

I am hoping your really understand the concept here and why its separated out the way it is. This pattern can be used for almost any kind of slider or content rotator. For example, if you want little clickable bullet indicators its easy to hook in:

```
var bullets = $('a.bullet');
bullets.on('click',function(){
     var index = $(this).index();
     bullets.removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');
     blockControl(index);
});
```

ect.

This can get even cooler if you make it OO style, so you can have multiple sliders on a page. But that is another story.

Comment: it s really great, i have to understand the way its works and the logic as you said, thanks so much :)

Comment: so i tried you re code, i dont  understand this :  blocks.hide().eq(index).show();  because this block are generated by thumbnail, the firt state for block is hide, when user clic on the thumbnail it open the block correpsondind to the thumb id, but if user clic on prev or next it works, but if after he clic on another thumb,  the prev or next buton dont go on, i have to work hard ;)

Comment: oh they are thumbnails! I didn't know that. Either way that is where you would but that logic. blocks.hide() was to hide all blocks, then .eq selects the block you want to show and .show shows it.

Answer (score 1):

Given your new requirements, I would do this:

The idea is to have the active element as a class, and you change the active element to the previous or next element when you click the prev or next button. And in CSS, you say that all slides are hidden except the active one that is displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="target" class="cible" style="height: 240px;">   
     <div id="211" class="slide">211</div>
     <div id="491" class="slide active">491</div>
    <div id="496" class="slide">496</div>
</div>
<!-- same next and prev buttons as yours -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.slide {
  display:none;   
}
.active {
 display:block;   
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    activeElem = $("#target .active");
    if (!activeElem .is(':last-child')) {
     activeElem .removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    }
});
// similar click event for the $("#prev") button
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/guz7D/

---

Based on the same idea, I have modified the code to include a fadeIn of the new element:

```
activeElem .removeClass('active').fadeOut(0).next().addClass('active').fadeIn(400);
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/guz7D/1/

Answer (score 0):

You really should take a jQuery pluggin for that. For example, [the nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) is a good polyvalent slider plugin.

If you want something very simple, you have the jQuery plugin [tiny casousel](http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/).

Comment: If it's an exercise, then build your own. But looking at the inner working of those can give you some insights.

Comment: hi , could give an advice to resolve the problem i update the code in the main comment, if you could take a look thanks